# use der or dass?

Tags: subordinate-clause

In a phrase like

> Wir werden jeden Planeten erkunden, der die Sonne umkreist.

could I also use dass? Making the phrase

> Wir werden jeden Planeten erkunden, dass die Sonne umkreist.

Comment: Why do you think it should be `dass`?

Comment: Because the "der" in the first phrase has the meaning of "that". Which to me seems to be the same meaning of "dass".

Comment: It's different. It's never "dass" if you can replaced "that" by "which" in English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it can be answered by [a thesaurus/dictionary](https://www.dict.cc/?s=dass), assuming the difference between a relative pronoun and a conjunction is known.

Comment: @infinitezero: "Wir werden jedes Gebilde erkunden, das die Sonne umkreist."

Comment: Ah, der Vorschlag war "dass", das habe ich übersehen. Nun, "dass" geht wirklich nicht.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off: no! These are completely different words.

"Der" is a *Pronomen* here and has about the function of "which". In fact "der" could be replaced by "welcher", which is the direct German counterpart of "which".

Notice, that *Pronomen* (pronouns) share the grammatical gender with the *Nomen* (noun) they stand for and look like the respective *Artikel* (article):

> der Planet, der [...] ("der Planet", maskulinum)
> die Sonne, die [...] ("die Sonne", femininum)
> das Sternbild, das [...] ("das Sternbild", neutrum)

The first "der" ("die", "das") is in fact the *Artikel*, the second is the *Pronomen*. I suppose you confused "dass" with "das", but that would be wrong too, because if "der" is correct the *Nomen* is a *Maskulinum* and for "das" to be correct it would have to be a *Neutrum*. It would be possible to replace the Pronomen with the respective form of "welch-" - also dependent on the gener of the *Nomen*:

> der Planet, welcher [...] ("der Planet", maskulinum)
> die Sonne, welche [...] ("die Sonne", femininum)
> das Sternbild, welches [...] ("das Sternbild", neutrum)

"dass" (notice the 2 "s", don't confuse with "das"!), also "sodass" or "auf dass", has a completely different function: it signifies (upon other things) finality. You are right, it can (in this function) be translated with "that", but *only* in the sense of "so that".

> Er sang, dass die Scheiben klirrten.
> <sub>He sang (so) that the windows rattled.</sub>

The clanking windows follow from his singing.